# Sharepoint 2010 discussion comments and replies

Tags: 2010, discussion-board

We are having the issue where in a discussion list, the replies or comments can be deleted or edited by any user, as any other user forum, it should be only by the user who cread the comment.

How can I fix this? security settings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Discussion forum > List Settings > Advanced Settings > Item Level Permissions

should take care of that. See the screenshot. Select "Create items and edit items that were created by the user" in the `Create and Edit access` section.

[image]

Comment: I just did that and its correct, however I logged with a user who is in the visitors group and he could change it. What I noticed that everyone in the visitors group has Design, Contribute and Limited Access in the discussion list, is it maybe because of the design permission level?

Comment: Yes, it would be because of the Design permission level. If you want visitors to be able to use the discussion board, they only need Contribute permission.